# Smoothie.js Charts is not working with JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, live-streaming, smoothie.js

Below is the HTML document that is implementing a Smoothie.js live streaming chart. On their own, timeSeries.append() and getJSON() methods work perfectly fine, but timeSeries.append() seems to not allow JSON data values.

The program gets stuck in the count() function; I added a document.write() method to see if it would output (see below) and it did not.

I thought maybe it was because the JSON data. when parsed, would be a string. So I took the data and made it a string and then an int.

But that didn't work.

I've been experimenting and nothing works like how I need it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click to open the live PeopleCount chart </button>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Manaal123/smoothie/master/smoothie.js"></script>
    <canvas id="chart" width="700" height="350"></canvas>
    <style>
      div.smoothie-chart-tooltip {
        background: #999;
        padding: 1em;
        margin-top: 20px;
        font-family: consolas;
        color: white;
        font-size: 17px;
        pointer-events: none;
      }

    </style>
    <script>
      var chart = new SmoothieChart({
          interpolation: 'step',
          grid: {
            fillStyle: '#ffffff',
            strokeStyle: '#c0c0c0',
            verticalSections: 10
          },
          labels: {
            fillStyle: '#000000',
            fontSize: 16,
            precision: 0
          },
          tooltip: true,
          maxValue: 10,
          minValue: 0,
          timestampFormatter: SmoothieChart.timeFormatter
        }),

        timeSeries = new TimeSeries();
      chart.addTimeSeries(timeSeries, {
        strokeStyle: 'blue',
        lineWidth: 1,
        fillStyle: 'rgba(0,128,255,0.30)'
      });

      function count() {
        $.getJSON("http://192.168.20.193:8001/count", function(result) {
          temp = result.data.count;
        });
        document.write("hi");
        temp = parseInt(temp, 10);
        return temp;
      }

      function myFunction() {
        chart.streamTo(document.getElementById('chart'), 100);
        setInterval(function() {
            timeSeries.append(new Date().getTime(), count());
        }, 5000);

      }
      var temp;

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`count()` is returning `undefined` because `$.getJSON` is asynchronous and you are returning `temp` before it is set in the callback. I would rewrite count() to something like

```
function count(callback) {
    $.getJSON("http://192.168.20.193:8001/count", function(result) {
        return callback(parseInt(result.data.count, 10));
    });
}
```

Now you have a way to know when `count(...)` is finished (when the callback function is called)

Then I would rewrite the way you call it like

```
setInterval(function() {
    count(function(temp){
        timeSeries.append(new Date().getTime(), temp);
    })
}, 5000);
```

Doing it this way ensures you wait for the request to your server to finish before setting data on the chart. If you would like to learn more I would suggest googling around with the word `asynchronous`.